# API specifications

Tags: architecture, api-design

I'm looking for the best way to share API specifications before developments.
I found lots of tool such as Swagger for the documentation to use the API. Here, I'd like to specify the API before implementation to share with customers/team to make sure we're aligned.
I find swagger a bit heavy for that, any tool/templates for such documentation?

Thanks,
David

Comment: A lot of this is language/framework dependent... What are you using.

Comment: I'm using C#.NET